# Is it possible to achieve following with Rails (+ Nesta): myapp.com/blog/1/post/4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, blogs, models, nestacms

I am trying various CMS for current project and Nesta looks interesting. I wonder though, how (if it is at all possible) one would model an app, where multiple users can create blogs via Nesta integrated into an existing Rails app?

I guess, I have to mount Nesta via Rack, but how to make it so that there is a possibility for each user to start a new blog?

Smth like: http://myapp.com/blog/1/post/4

would be really great.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks a log

P.S. I am not married to Nesta (although it looks nice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Nesta, but to do some URLs like that, you should look at nested resources : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources.

Comment: do you think it would be possible to combine this approach with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167096/nesta-cms-and-rails3-integration-adding-blog-to-an-exiting-rails-3-application ?

Comment: so I actually followed the advice and not using cms.